# Query returning sql string with wrong parameters

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am currently working on fixing some SQL injection bugs in my project.

Here is my current sql string:

```
String sql = "select * from :table order by storenum";
```

Here is how I am setting the parameters:

```
SQLQuery query =  sess.createSQLQuery(sql).setParameter("table", table);
```

(table is a string that is passed in through a method)

Whenever I run the program I get something like this:

```sql
select * from ? order by storenum
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't dynamically bind table names, only values, so you'll have to resort to string manipulation/concatenation to get the table name dynamically. However, you would probably want to escape it to avoid SQL Injections.